# With() and Get() in eloquent laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a RESTful API in laravel 4 and I have the following command

```
return News::with('User')->get(array('id', 'body', 'created_at', 'categorie_id', 'user_id'))->find(1)->toJson();
```

and it return:

> {"id":"1","body":"hola a todos", "created_at":"2014-09-11 17:18:01","categorie_id":"3","user_id":"1","user":{"id":"1","nick":"angel","description":null,"photo":null,"origin":"España","created_at":"2014-09-11
>   17:18:00","updated_at":"2014-09-11 17:18:00"}}

It return the selected columns that I have chosen from "News" (id, body, relevancia, lat, lng, created_at, categorie_id, user_id) It is ok, but I also want select columns from "User", in the example I don't want that json return updated_at (from "user")

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `hidden` property in your `User` model like:

```
protected $hidden = array('updated_at');
```

That's it. You may add more fields in the `array` to exclude from your `json` result. Also you may try something like this (Instead of `hidden` property):

```
return News::with(array('User' => function($q) {
    $q->select('username', 'email'); // select fields from user table
}))->get(array('id', 'body');
```

This way you don't have to add the `hidden` property but you may specify the fields you want to select from your `users` table so you may exclude the field from query but by default it's not hidden.

Comment: Yes, I know that option but I am searching a more flexible solution that allow me include "updated_at" from user sometimes and not disable it for all queries.

Comment: Then follow the `second` approach.